# How fragile are powered-off mechanical USB 2.5" hard disks really while transported?

Tags: hard-drive, security, external-hard-drive, physical-damage, physical-wear

I'm going to be forced to move from here sooner or later, likely sooner.

All my pathetic life's digital data is on a bunch of (redundant in 6+ copies now) 2.5" (and one 3.5", the oldest) mechanical USB hard disks which spend nearly all of their time in a safe.

Naturally, I won't be moving with them inside the safe.

I plan to empty the safe from the disks, wrap each one individually in a cloth (or several cloths), then put all of those together into a big bundle which I wrap other, bigger cloths around until it's a big ball of padded external HDDs.

Also will do the same for the internal SSDs and one internal HDD that's actually in my computer. (Won't have them rattling around in there.)

All this will be padded multiple extra times and put in a backpack which I will carry on my back or holding in my hands, or keeping in my lap while riding the car to the new location. I will try to make sure that all of the HDDs are facing the right side up, and that they are as "flat" as possible compared to the ground.

Surely this must be sufficient for them to not rattle 'n roll themselves to a broken state?

After all, they are powered down, with the "needles" not hovering above the discs inside. Is this not a safe strategy? Is it really important to have them "lying down" and "the right side up"? Are there dangers on the way? Something I should think about that I haven't considered?

I know that there are professional packages made for rich companies to transport their HDDs, but I don't really have any money to spare, and since I will be personally holding the heavily padded backpack, surely that must be much better than just having a package in a truck's cargo?

Am I possibly even *overthinking* this?

Comment: I've literally thrown my hard drives in my bag unprotected and they were fine. If I was worried, I'd buy a stack of padded envelopes and throw them in. Don't forget USB HDDs are designed to be portable.  Also depending on how you move them, leaving internal drives in a PC, packaging the PC well  and moving the whole PC seems safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overthinking it.

If (unpowered) hard-drives were that sensitive nobody could transport laptops or desktop computers.

All modern (this millennium) drives will auto-lock the drive-heads in a safe position when powered off.

Just put them in a box with some padding (a layer of bubble wrap plastic or a sheet of foam rubber) so they don't bump into one anther during transport.
That will suffice as long as you are not throwing the box around.
Physical orientation isn't going to matter.

I routinely drive around with several laptops and or desktop computers in the back of my car. I have a 2 inch thick sheet of foam-rubber on the bottom of the trunk and I just put the computers on that pad. That is all the precautions I take and I never had an issue in the 20 years I have been doing that. (I do make sure the laptops are really shutdown and not in hibernate/sleep mode. I don't want to risk one spontaneously booting up while I'm driving.)

Comment: If you are really worried.  You can buy foam and/or HDD carrying cases (plastic cases). Both are likely overkill. Since in theory any box you pack won't be moving that much anyways.